# Should I use @embedded or @OneToOne when designing app about user´s statistics?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, database-design

I am designing an dashboard app, which should serve as user´s portal for searching job.

My task is to present user´s statistics (CV details, app settings, assignments) and available job opportunities (and default search settings which can be saved) in various tabs.

While I know, that I should have table with open jobs and theirs details, I am not sure, if I should use @Embeddable or @OneToOne annotation. I got recommendation to not use @Embedded everywhere, only in some cases, but on the other side I mean value tables, which do not have sense without user table.

I have these tables:

- *User*

- *CV stats* - every user has its own

- *Advertisement* - every user has its own, only one ad at one time

- *Default Search Settings* - every user has its own

- *App settings* - every user has its own

- *Open jobs* - all users share

- *User`s assignments* - already taken jobs with their details

What would you recommend?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/embeddables.html), you would use `@Embedded` if you intend to include the attributes in the parent entity. As you realize every object as an separate table, you should probably go with `@OneToOne`/`@OneToMany` relationships only